# C++ openCV waitKey(0) not working?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int isSquare(String fileName);
int main() {
    String imgName = "C:/A.jpg";
    isSquare(imgName);
}
int isSquare(String fileName) {
    Mat img;
    img = cv::imread(fileName, IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (img.empty()) {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //namedWindow("display", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("display", img);
    waitKey(0);
    cout << "hi";
    destroyWindow("display");
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I'm currently messing around with openCV 3.30, C++. Now I'm trying to open an image, but the display window just kept disappear when I execute above code. I commented namedWindow("display", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); because openCV document says cv:imshow() will automatically create one, and if I un-comment that line I got one gray window, one image window like this.
[image]

I don't want to got that gray window, and key input for waitKey(0) works only when I focus on gray window, not on image window. 
So I made that line as a comment. but if I do that, when I execute that code the image window disappears instantly as if I don't have waitKey(0) code. Clearly waitKey(0) is not working because cout<<"hi"; after waitKey(0) was executed.

Am I missing something? Is the document wrong and using namedWindow necessary? All I wanted was to get rid of that gray window... any words of wisdom is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try removing `destroyWindow("display");` as well. You can look at the examples [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Comment: Sadly that didn't work :( thanks though

Comment: The code seems correct. Why so we see 2 "diplay" windows opened? Do you launch the program twice at the same time?

Comment: No, I'm 100% sure I launched only once. If I commented imshow and uncommented namedWindow, then only gray window is showing. If I uncommented both then result is like above image. so I thought commenting only namedWindow results in showing only image... *sigh*

Comment: `namedWindow` is useless in this context and can be safely removed. I don't get why you get two windows, however. Are you sure the _name_ you give to `namedWindow` and `imshow` is exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, they are both "display".  but do note that I got two windows when I uncommented namedWindow, and if I remove namedWindow then image window just disappear instantly. oh the headache...

Comment: Is this the **exact** code you're using? This works as expected for me

Comment: yup, exact code. well then... I guess it's just my machine's problem. thank you for code confirming.